# Images in the first bootstrap tab are smaller

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap tabs I have galleries. However, the pictures in the first tab are smaller than in the others. 
It must be some Bootstrap CSS-related problem because other galleries also are smaller only in the first tab. It's also not the tab group itself, because it happens in all new-created tab groups.

And the code, as you can see it's the same gallery:

```
<ul id="galTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#gal2" data-toggle="tab">Biuro projektowe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#gal3" data-toggle="tab">Kierowanie budowami</a></li>
    <li><a href="#gal4" data-toggle="tab">Zabytki</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="galTabContent" class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="gal2">
      <?php echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_gridgallery id="1"]'); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="gal3">
      <?php echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_gridgallery id="1"]'); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="gal4">
      <?php echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_gridgallery id="1"]'); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to be clear... are you talking about the image on the right?  The `id="gal4"`

Comment: I am talking about all the images in the gallery in the first tab so in `<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="gal2">`.
In all the three tabs there is the same gallery but I don't know why the picures in the gallery in the first tab are always smaller than in the 2nd and the 3rd tab.

Take a look at the live example and you'll understand

Comment: Dandy, when I view these it looks the same size. Even when I line them up along the top. (Chrome)

Comment: Dandy, Yes I see that now. The code is very compressed for these tabs, Can you try this... Look to see if on tab 2/3 the width of the container is set wider than tab 1 container. If it is the images may resize to fit across and therefore grow in height.

Answer (score 0):

I saw different inline styles in `.wonderplugin-gridgallery-item`, widths particularly. You must verify `<?php echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_gridgallery id="1"]'); ?>`.

Comment: It cannot be the plugin itself because as you can see in all the tabs the same gallery is used. So it has the same CSS. For the sake of the example now I've changed the galleries to id="2", the same situation. Thus, it's not the gallery.